# Erro #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql

Estava a tentar colocar um das minhas tabelas como `primary key`.
Assim que tento aparece a mensagem:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Os dados estão preenchidos e estão mais ou menos assim:

[image: Dados]

Tentei colocar como chave primaria o `Sub_Id`.

Comment: Você não conseguiu incluir um registro ou não conseguiu definir SUB_ID como chave primária? Acho que sua pergunta pode ser "melhorada" está um pouco confusa... parece que vocÊ está obtendo erro por tentar inserir um registro com um SUB_ID que já existe e se ele é primary key, realmente, não pode.

Comment: não consegui colocar o SUB_ID como chave primaria.

Comment: Que ação você está executando quando obtem este erro? Está alterando a tabela ou fazendo um insert?

Comment: Estou a tentar colocar o Sub_ID como chave primaria. é quando me dá o erro.

Comment: os dados ja estao preenchidos mas quero alterar e tenho a mensagem a dizer : This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

Comment: Eu tive este problema com meu vBulletin, e troquei a engine de innodb pra myisam e foi resolvido...

Comment: O tipo já está como MyIsam e não funciona a mesma

Comment: Se colocar outro dado qualquer como chave primaria existe problema?

Comment: faz um select e vê se tem alguem q repete o sub_id... se repetir ele não aceitará mesmo.

Comment: Dica: Você pode selecionar somente os campos id_area e sub_id da tabela: `SELECT id_area, sub_id FROM tabela`, ao invés de `*`

Answer (score 5):

Como informado pela mensagem de erro, o campo `sub_id` não é único e se repete.

Me parece que sua tabela possui uma chave composta entre `area_id` e `sub_id`. Tente definir **ambas** as colunas como chave primaria:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_AreaId_SubId PRIMARY KEY (area_id,sub_id);
```

Você também pode criar uma nova coluna para ser a chave primaria para essa combinação de `area_id` e `sub_id` (isso é chamado de [*surrogate key*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277091/surrogate-key-e-natural-key)):

```
ALTER TABLE tabela
ADD id_pk INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

Mais informações sobre o `ALTER TABLE` na [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

Faça a seguinte query e veja a causa do problema:

`SELECT SUB_ID, COUNT(*) TOTAL FROM TABELA GROUP BY SUB_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
-- On Mysql run:
set LAST_INSERT_ID= (SELECT id FROM TABLE_NAME order by id desc limit 1)

-- On Postgres, for error duplicate key value violates unique constraint ...
-- Run
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('TABLE_NAME', 'id'), coalesce(max(id)+1, 1), false) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).