# Surrogate Key e Natural Key

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, modelagem, data-warehouse

Estou estudando sobre *data warehouse*, mas fiquei confusa quanto aos conceitos de SK e NK.

Pelo que entendi, em um DW, uma *natural key* seria uma coluna do tipo *foregin key* na tabela dimensão, da coluna que é PK referente a mesma tabela no banco de dados. Ou seja, uma cópia daquela coluna.

Já a *surrogate key* seria uma PK da tabela dimensão no DW.

Exemplificando:
BD

```
tabela_usuario  
id_usuario (PK):  
U100  
U101  
U102...
```

DW

```
dimensao_usuario  
sk_usuario (PK), nk_usuario (FK)  
1, U100  
2, U101  
3, U102
```

Meu entendimento está correto?

Comment: Observe que há 2 conceituações básicas no universo DW: Bill Inmon vs. Ralph Kimball. Vide https://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/inmon-kimball.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [chave substituta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) (*surrogate*) ou artificial é um dado que é criado para fins de controle do banco de dados, ela não existe fora da solução de software sendo desenvolvida. Geralmente é um ID numérico único, estável (não muda), sequencial e autoincrementado. Você tem algum controle sobre ele. É simplesmente isso.

A [chave natural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) é aquela que existe fora da aplicação e está sendo usada como chave. Um CPF ou CNPJ é uma chave natural, ela existe independente do banco de dados. Pode ser até um nome, embora incomum, pode ser um e-mail, telefone, ou número de algum documento, pode ser um código EAN ou outro padronizado por alguma indústria, enfim, pode ser qualquer dado que sirva como uma chave e você não tem controle sobre ele ou tem um controle limitado, é uma propriedade inerente do objeto real que está sendo cadastrado no banco de dados.

Se a chave é primária ou não é uma questão que não importa aí. Se for primária precisa ser única, idealmente curta, previsível, que você tenha controle e seja estável, por isso é muito comum usar uma chave substituta.

Nada impede usar chave natural como primária, só pode causar problemas, as pessoas acham que nunca terão problema usando-a, e um dia acaba descobrindo que há problema.

A impressão que me dá é que `id_ usuario` usa uma chave substituta, e `dimensao_usuario` a usa como chave secundária (estrangeira). Por que a mesma chave que era substituta passar ser natural quando usada em outro lugar? Pra mim, nesse exemplo, só existem chaves substitutas, a não ser que `U100` seja um dado existente fora do banco de dados que foi transportada para ele, aí esse dado nas duas tabelas é natural e a `sk_usuario` é que seria substituta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Há um ótimo artigo sobre chaves naturais, chaves primárias, chaves substitutas (*surrogate keys*) etc em [Primary Key Primer for SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/primary-key-primer-for-sql-server/). Observe que essa conceituação independe do contexto de DW.

Eis trecho sobre a escolha entre chave natural ou substituta:

**Should I use a natural or surrogate key?**
*A key is just a combination of column (attribute) values that provide an obvious way of distinguishing rows, and a natural, or ‘domain’ key is one that has meaning outside the database environment, such a Longitude/Latitude.
Many people argue for a general rule that keys must be natural (or perversely that they shouldn't be) or that they must be immutable. I've even heard it said that all joins must be on key values. As always, it depends. On this topic, there are very few hard and fast rules, because sometimes there are conflicting requirements between the knowledge level and the requirements of implementation.*
(...)
*Surrogate keys are the normal way of getting round the complexities of trying to handle natural keys that are ungainly or don’t quite conform to your business rules. These are fine if they are kept private within the database: otherwise, they are a form of technical debt. They make the coding of databases easier but are disliked by book-keepers, accountants, retailers or anyone else who has to handle
them. They aren't human-friendly. Sometimes, surrogate keys ‘escape’ into the world if exposed as ‘reference numbers’ and take on a permanent and intended meaning that prevents any refactoring or renumbering within the database.*

Sugiro a leitura desse artigo.

No caso de *data warehouse* (DW) o enfoque altera um pouco, por causa da temporalidade. Por exemplo, um determinado produto pode ter sua codificação modificada em determinado momento; isso fica transparente caso no DW tenha-se optado pelo uso de chave substituta para identificar os produtos. Mesmo que no banco de dados do [OLTP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLTP) a codificação tenha sido alterada, no banco de dados do DW ela permanece imutável, possibilitando acompanhar o produto ao longo de sua existência.

Há também outros motivos para a utilização de chave substituta em DW. Um deles é que a informação sobre um mesmo objeto pode ter codificações diferentes, dependendo da origem, quando o DW é alimentado a partir de diversas origens (inclusive de fora da empresa). Desta forma, a chave substituta escolhida para o objeto passa a funcionar como padronização.

Isto pode ser confirmado pela definição de [Surrogate Keys](https://www.kimballgroup.com/1998/05/surrogate-keys/) presente no sítio web do Kimball Group, onde é mencionado que *Actually, a surrogate key in a data warehouse is more than just a substitute for a natural key. In a data warehouse, a surrogate key is a necessary generalization of the natural production key and is one of the basic elements of data warehouse design*.

Aliás, esse verbete reforça que *Every join between dimension tables and fact tables in a data warehouse environment should be based on surrogate keys, not natural key*.

---

TRADUÇÃO DE TRECHOS ACIMA ORIGINALMENTE EM INGLÊS
Uma chave é apenas a combinação de valores de coluna (atributo) que fornece uma maneira óbvia para diferenciar linhas e uma chave natural (ou de domínio) é uma que tenha significado fora do ambiente do banco de dados, como latitude/longitude. Várias pessoas sustentam por uma regra geral que as chaves
devam ser naturais (ou teimosamente que não devam) ou que devam ser imutáveis. Eu mesmo escutei que todas as junções devem ser através de valores de chave. Como sempre, depende. Sobre este tema há pouquíssimas regras rígidas e rápidas, porque às vezes há exigências conflitantes entre o nível de
conhecimento e os requisitos de implementação.
(...)
Chaves substitutas são a formal usual de contornar as complexidades de tentar lidar com chaves naturais que são desajeitadas ou que não estejam em conformidade com as regras do negócio. Isto está correto se elas são mantidas restritas ao banco de dados: caso contrário, elas são um tipo de dívida técnica. Elas facilitam a codificação dos bancos de dados mas são rejeitadas por guarda-livros, contadores, revendedores ou qualquer pessoa que tenha que utilizá-las. Elas não são amigáveis. Às vezes, chaves substitutas escapam para o mundo se expostas como ‘números referenciais’ e assumem um sentido permanente que impede qualquer modificação ou renumeração interna no banco de dados.