# Dúvidas sobre ID nos cadastros de um sistema retaguarda web

Tags: ux

Estou desenvolvendo um app web comercial e venho do mundo dos apps desktop. Percebi que na maioria dos sites de apps comerciais são ignorados os IDs ou códigos dos cadastros para os clientes. Claro que no banco de dados eles são fundamentais para os relacionamentos, mas tenho essa dúvida de deixá-los visíveis ou não nas *grids* e telas de cadastro.

[image: Exemplo de tela com ID mostrado]

Na empresa onde trabalho, usamos um sistema retaguarda desktop no qual todos os cadastros possuem a matrícula (ID ou Código) e eles são muito importantes para os clientes usarem para relacionarem um cadastro com o outro. Inclusive, quando migramos os dados de uma empresa concorrente para o nosso, os clientes fazem questão de preservarem os antigos códigos de clientes, produtos, grupos, fornecedores, etc.

O que é mais adequado fazer?

Comment: Talvez seria mais baseada em opinião, mas acho que dá pra salvar a questão sintetizando um pouco e mudando as tags que não tem a ver...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis concordo. Eu tive um pouco de dificuldade em compreender o que o OP deseja, e se há uma dúvida especifica.

Comment: Acho que a tag adequada seria UX

Comment: Uma das vantagens de deixar visível é que pode facilitar numa busca. Muitos sistemas até hoje usam códigos como uma espécie de referencia há algo (geralmente é a chave primária), claro que hoje em dia as coisas estão mudando. Sendo assim, é melhor você pensar a respeito, e ver o que você tem a ganhar ou perder com isso. Você poderia consultar os usuários e ver se a ocultação do código na interface traz algum beneficio ou malefício.

Comment: Colega @LINQ, desculpe mas eu discordo. "Isso" cabe sim no escopo do site. Vide as discussões de escopo no meta e o tanto de perguntas e respostas de UX que já existem no site principal. Talvez a pergunta esteja de um jeito que pareça meramente opinativa (o "o que acham disso" denota bem o problema da pergunta), mas UX *sempre* teve (e sempre terá) essa discussão.

Comment: Tranquilo, @LuizVieira, se desculpa não. Comunidade é pra ser assim mesmo, onde um erra o outro acerta e assim a gente mantém tudo nos conformes. Tinha me passado despercebido uma possível discussão acerca de UX e agora faz completo sentido. Me deixei levar pelo tom opinativo da publicação.

Comment: @LINQ Sem problemas. Obrigado. :)

Comment: Entendo a relação que os clientes utilizam com os códigos... muitos vendedores sabem os códigos dos produtos de cabeça, ou utilizam uma etiqueta com um "codigo interno" menor que o EAN pra ir adicionando os produtos com maior agilidade (nada que um leitor não resolva, mas não é assim que funciona em pequenos comércios do interior...) há também casos onde o cliente utiliza o código do sistema antigo, pra relacionar com um arquivo físico de fichas (sim, ainda vejo esse tipo de coisa por aqui...)... se fosse fazer algo hoje, certamente só mostraria o essencial, no máximo alguma função pra mostrar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ponto-chave da sua pergunta é esse:

> "[...] todos os cadastros possuem a matrícula (ID ou Código) e eles
>   são muito importantes para os clientes usarem para relacionarem um
>   cadastro com o outro [...]"

Sim, eles certamente são importantes... **para a empresa que criou e usa o sistema**. Primeiramente, é um incômodo para um usuário ter de lembrar um código, qualquer que seja e por mais curto que seja. Em segundo lugar, em termos de dados de identificação, nada é mais importante para o cliente do que seu próprio nome. Certamente os clientes desses cadastros que você menciona prefeririam usar seus nomes para se relacionar. Não acredita? Pergunte aos clientes. Ou faça um exercício de empatia e se coloque no lugar deles com algum serviço que você usa (telefonia, entretenimento, etc).

Se o código é algo realmente necessário ao negócio, facilite a vida do cliente colocando-o em um cartão. Isso não é nenhuma ideia brilhante: as locadoras de filmes já faziam isso há muito tempo (na época em que ainda persistiam). Se você precisa de um código, deixe o cliente defini-lo. Isso se chama login, e geralmente se usa e-mail não somente pelo contato, mas pela unicidade.

Bom, agora, considerando como usuário não o cliente, mas a pessoa que lida com o cliente e usa essa interface para algum relacionamento, o código é ainda menos necessário. O que esse usuário precisa realmente saber é o nome do cliente, talvez seu email e outros dados da identidade do usuário ou de sua situação no negócio, dependendo do domínio do problema. De fato, em um sistema bem feito, as linhas dessa tabela já demonstram a ação que o usuário precisa tomar em relação àquele cliente, e se bobear até fazem a ligação telefônica (um exemplo de telemarketing) mesmo exibindo o telefone. Por que então o ID seria necessário além de seu uso nas tabelas do banco, isto é, por que seria necessário na interação?

O que costuma ocorrer é que o tal ID é tão importante para a empresa que ela empurra goela abaixo do cliente e do usuário que atende este, mas quase nunca tal código é realmente necessário. Veja que fazer UX é justamente se colocar essas perguntas (difíceis e as vezes incômodas para quem já está acostumado com o tal do "mundo das apps desktop").

Comment: Eu trabalhei numa montadora onde se usava códigos para se referenciar a uma determinada peça, como eram muitas peças (milhares de modelos) e o nome delas eram longos e técnicos demais, o código ajudava, mas o código não era a chave primária do banco e sim para ajudar a identificar grupos de peças, como as peças de um caminhão que sempre iniciava pelos dígitos `509` ou outros grupos de modelos. Neste contexto, os códigos sem dúvida ajudavam, mas só os usuários do sistema, os clientes não precisavam saber o código que era usado internamente na fabrica.

Answer (score 3):

Você é que precisa responder a questão, como toda questão de UX.

Você precisa mostrar esse ID por alguma razão? O usuário precisa estar ciente disto? Talvez para obter algum suporte? Pode mostrar opcionalmente?

Eu não colocaria nada que não seja muito necessário. E mesmo que seja por motivos secundários eu criaria uma forma opcional de mostrar a informação, sei lá, um modo avançado ou de suporte.

Seria diferente se isto for um código de cliente ou algo assim. Mesmo neste caso não sou fã da ideia. Prefiro deixar o usuário mais confortável lindando com uma informação que faça parte do domínio dele.

Não mostrar não quer dizer que não esteja presente em todo o sistema.

Acho a afirmação da última frase meio estranha, mas se isto é verdade pode ser um motivo para usar esse código. Porém esse código por vir de algo externo não parece ser uma chave primária, pelo menos não deveria ser. Aí o ID ainda se torna necessário e tem um motivo a mais para ele não ser mostrado. Mas o código natural seria. Não confunda ID de banco de dados (chave substituta) com chave natural que o usuário entende.

Veja mais em [Surrogate Key e Natural Key](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101).