# Diferença e utilização entre Primary Key e Foreign Key

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária

Fiz uma modelagem do banco de dados relacionando algumas tabelas e no final de tudo foi me dito que estava errado por não possuir as chaves PK e FK. A questão é, como eu diferencio uma Primary Key de uma Foreign Key? Para que as duas servem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A **chave primária** é o dado que você precisa para controle do acesso às linhas da tabelas. Ela deve ser única e por isso não pode ter valor nulo (teoricamente poderia ter uma chave nula, mas não faz muito sentido). Ela dá a identidade para a linha, é por ela que você pode confiar que sempre será usada para acesso direto à linha desejada. É comum que seja usado um identificador numérico sequencial para isso. Veja mais em [Surrogate Key e Natural Key](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101).

A **chave estrangeira** é usada para relacionamento com outra tabela. Em boa parte dos casos ela será a chave primária de outra tabela. Por isso pode ser nula (não tem relacionamento) ou duplicata (mais de um item em uma tabela se relaciona com o mesmo item de outra tabela).

Em geral modelagem depende de experiência. E experiência depende de ter capacidade de aprendizado. Experiência de forma alguma é o tempo que a pessoa faz aquilo ou quantas vezes já fez. Isso até seria experiência quantitativa, que não tem valor algum, a experiência que vale é a qualitativa, aquela que você faz uma vez, alguém ou as consequências te mostram com o tempo que estava errado e deve fazer melhor. Cada vez mais vemos as pessoas optando, por toda sua vida, só seguir o que os outros fazem, ver superficialmente como se faz, aí a pessoa nunca se torna experiente. Inclusive para adquirir experiência é necessário adquirir experiência. Tem que quebrar o círculo vicioso para começar evoluir.

A chave primária com esse conhecimento básico (incluindo o *link* acima) já dá para entender a necessidade dela e na maioria dos casos a escolha é simples e óbvia, é uma chave substituta numérica sequencial.

A estrangeira é mais complicada, nem sempre que é novato enxerga claramente o que precisa para relacionar um dado com outro, mas também não é tão difícil. Pensa nela como uma palavra que você precisa saber para procurar em um dicionário. A outra tabela relacionada é o seu dicionário para esse caso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).