# Toda tabela deve ter primary key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Acredito que minha pergunta é tanto conceitual quanto técnica.

O meu problema todo começou quando fiz um banco de dados SQL Server e nele havia algumas tabelas sem chave primária, tais tabelas serviriam dentro da aplicação para que gravasse registros de chaves estrangeiras, da tabela produtos para a tabela pedidos e da tabela produtos para tabela catalogo, apenas para que eu pudesse fazer os `joins` dentro dos `selects`.

Minha aplicação deveria usar o ASP.NET MVC por conta das exigências do curso em utilizar certas tecnologias, ai no meu grupo decidimos por utilizar o Entity Framework.

Até ai tudo bem dentro do SQL Manager tudo funcionando, mas quando o `.edmx` gerava os meus *models* e contexto as tabelas que não continham uma chave primaria não apareciam na aplicação.

Talvez tenha sido imperícia minha e por isso lhes pergunto seria só no caso de usar o Entity que eu deveria usar chave primaria em todas as tabelas ou usar é um padrão para qualquer aplicação com banco de dados?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Infelizmente tem uma decisão um pouco ruim aí por ter escolhido usar uma [tecnologia que está praticamente abandonada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101) (talvez escolha do curso). Nada crítico por ser algo para um curso e o projeto será abandonado (eu acho), mas ao mesmo tempo está aprendendo com algo que não tem futuro. Seria melhor ter usado o Entity Framework Core.

Sim, o EF exige que tenha uma chave primária justamente porque quase toda tabela deveria ter e ele precisa ter "onde se agarrar". E de fato todas tabelas em um banco de dados tem uma PK, em alguns casos ela fica invisível para você porque seu modelo pode não exigir isto, e aí você acha que não tem uma. Mas também quase sempre não ter uma chave primária explícita indica uma modelagem errada. Por que não precisa de uma? Sabe as consequências disto? Se não souber responder isto então pelo menos deve usar o padrão que é ter uma PK. Não é o ideal porque toda decisão deve ser justificada, mas a chance de errar diminui já que não ter PK é um caso bem excepcional.

Digo mais, quase sempre [a chave adequada é uma substituta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101), que é a usada pelo SGDB se nenhuma for fornecida por você. É muito raro uma natural ser adequada, porque mesmo que pareça, um dia pode não ser mais e aí terá trabalho arrumar tudo. O mesmo motivo que leva usar uma *surrogate* é o que leva ter uma PK explícita.

Não existe respostas absolutas para essas coisas. Eu sei que quase todo mundo quer acreditar que tem, que basta decorar uma regra e fazer sempre aquilo que estará certo, mas a única coisa certa é entender os fundamentos, saber os porquês de cada coisa, e aí tomar decisões de acordo com esse conhecimento. Hoje em dia grande parte dos problemas dos softwares (principalmente aqueles que não parecem ser problemas porque funcionam, apesar de não estar certo) é porque as decisões foram tomadas com base em regra automática e não com fundamento e considerando o caso concreto que está resolvendo.

A dúvida é só conceitual porque não tem um caso concreto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Nos casos de tabelas que envolvem apenas relacionamento entre outras tabelas, como citado por você, eu costumo criar uma PK "artificial" (um identity ou um guid).

Isso me facilita o acesso direto ao registro, pois precisarei informar apenas um "id" seja para alguma consulta, alteração ou exclusão.

Answer (score 1):

Nelson, as duas respostas acimas estão muito completas. Vou adicionar uma observação aqui a respeito de banco de dados NoSql.

Banco NoSql trabalham de uma forma completamente diferente dos bancos relacionais e, dependendo do contexto, você não precisa de *chave primária* somente de uma identificação do registro.

A título de conhecimento é válido. Abraço.