# Orientação a objetos: o que define a identidade de uma entidade?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, entidade

Sei que o conceito de identidade, nesse contexto, é abstrato e é justamente para deixá-lo mais tangível que fiz essa pergunta. Seguem as questões:

- Apenas id do banco de dados define a identidade de uma entidade?
- Qual o critério define a identidade que caracteriza uma entidade?
- Além do id do banco de dados, nomes e outras tipos de identificação (números, códigos e etc.) se encaixam nessa ideia de identidade que define uma entidade?

#### Observações para guiar as respostas

A entidade aqui é relacionada a objetos que representam coisas dentro de um projeto e não entidade do banco de dados. Ou seja, **entidade nessa questão é a contraparte dos value objects.**

Também não me refiro a como as linguagens de programação implementam a identidade internamente na memória. **Falo de objetos que são entidades da regra de negócio (e o que define a identidade neles).** Acho que esse conceito de entidade vem do DDD (não tenho conhecimentos dessa metodologia).

Comment: Identidade não é qualquer característica que determina univocamente uma instância desta entidade?

Comment: identidade é um atributo que define um valor único para identificar um elemento daquela entidade. ID é um, CPF por exemplo é a identidade fiscal de um cidadão, o nome pode ser o mesmo, mas o CPF não será, e por ai vai. O critério é simples: um atributo único, que não repita, que permita identificar um único elemento da entidade. Uma entidade por exemplo de Estado, poderia ser a sigla (AC, AL, AP, AM, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O que define a identidade de uma entidade?

Eu não gosto de definição do termo dado no contexto de orientação a objeto, por isso vou só colocar [o que está na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(object-oriented_programming)) para não dar uma definição minha:

> Uma identidade no design orientado a objetos e na análise orientada a objetos descreve a propriedade dos objetos que os diferencia de outros objetos. Isso está intimamente relacionado ao conceito filosófico de identidade.

Em termos de identidade real de objetos no sentido mais universal isso não encaixa bem, mas a pergunta tem um contexto mais específico.

> Apenas id do banco de dados define a identidade de uma entidade?

Não necessariamente, mas é muito comum que seja ele no banco de dados. Sugiro dar uma lida em [Surrogate Key e Natural Key](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101). O `id` pode ser o definidor da identidade daquela linha no banco de dados.

Não necessariamente é a identidade daquela entidade lógica do ponto de vista de modelagem do negócio. Pode ser um outro código, um número de documento, ou até um nome (mais raro). Até pode ser o `id` também, se o modelo do negócio ainda fizer sentido com isso.

Do ponto de vista do mecanismo do banco de dado a chave primária utilizada será a identidade, sendo o `id` ou não. Mas reforço que só vale para o SGDB, no modelo de negócio depende.

> Qual o critério define a identidade que caracteriza uma entidade?

Depende de cada entidade, o maior motivo é que ela seja única em toda coleção de dados. A identidade pode até ser composta por vários dados. No banco de dados costuma ser o `id` porque ele é único.

Do ponto de vista estrito de orientação a objetos não há regras tão específicas além da unicidade.

A pergunta é um pouco confusa por colocar a *tag* de OOP e falar de banco de dados, onde o termo tem significados diferentes, inclusive em alguns contextos, como DDD só para citar um, pode ter especificidades sobre essas regras.

Answer (score 3):

> a entidade aqui é relacionada a objetos que representam coisas dentro de um projeto e não entidade do banco de dados.

Como você disse, o conceito é abstrato. A identidade de um objeto é o que define que ele é aquele objeto específico, e não outro. As linguagens orientadas a objeto implementam isso, mas não necessariamente expõem essa implementação para o programador. Ou, mesmo que exponham, em geral não é necessário usá-la.

Falando no geral, a identidade de um objeto, em tempo de execução, é aquilo que será usado para representar o objeto no contexto de uma comparação de igualdade com outro objeto, por exemplo. Geralmente isso vai ser um valor (um número único) guardado em algum lugar da memória alocada pelo programa.